# Which of Pierre Boulez's composition(s) are considered unlistenable, and/or the (Modernist) Emperor's New Clothes?

Tags: modernism

I can brook listening to Boulez's 3 *Piano Sonatas, Le Marteau sans maître, Pli selon pli*, and *Répons*. **I've listened to Boulez's OTHER compositions THE PAST 20 YEARS, but nothing else of his resonates with me!**

Which Boulez's other compositions do musicologists judge to be merely Modernist [balderdash](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/51357), [pretentiousness](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/173317)?

I quote Robert Greenberg [(BA Music magna cum laude, Princeton, PhD music composition UC Berkeley)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Greenberg#Biography) in *Great Music of the 20th Century Course Guidebook*, p 114:

> - Most Ultraserialist music was created without any thought to how it might be perceived by an actual listener in real time. As a result, it should come as no surprise that most of this music makes no perceivable sense.
> - It is a most unfortunate fact that the seemingly random, frantic ugliness of the vast majority of Ultraserialist music and its rejection by the musical public actually served to reinforce the composers’ sense that they were on to something special. They thought that they were an aesthetic and intellectual elite.
> - In 1999, Boulez was asked in an interview to explain why so few Ultraserial works from the 1950s and 1960s were still performed. Boulez’s response constitutes one of the great understatements of all time: “Well, perhaps we did not take sufficiently into account the way music is perceived by the listener.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boulez's *total serialism* period lasted from about 1950 to 1952 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Boulez#Total_serialism)). Leaving aside aesthetic judgement, this would be his "least listenable" music insofar as it was expressively inflexible, and even Boulez has recognized it as a failed, but necessary, experiment.

> Asked whether it should still be listened to as music, Boulez replied: "I am not terribly eager to listen to it. But for me it was an experiment that was absolutely necessary." (ibid.)

However, at least two pieces from that period, *Polyphonie X* and *Structures*, are still significant reference points for theoretical study.

The pieces mentioned as tolerable in the question come both before and after Total Serialism, so at that level, Greenberg's quotations are less relevant to Boulez's compositions since, and especially in the last 20 years (i.e., since 2000). In fact, between 2000 and his death in 2016, Boulez published only four works ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compositions_by_Pierre_Boulez)), his career increasingly having focused on conducting since giving up his post as director of IRCAM in 1992.